# How to execute local queries with breeze EntityManager in Edmunds sample?

Tags: breeze

I'm a newby to breeze and wonder if it is possible to run local queries against entities that have been fetched using a REST service like in Edmunds sample.

Is it possible to execute local queries using breeze EntityManager after reading the entities from a remote REST service?

I tried to extend Edmunds sample app with a local query that will be called after all Makes have been loaded:

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Make:#Edmunds")
        .where("niceName", "startsWith", "A")
    return manager.executeQueryLocally(query).then(returnResults);
```

When I execute the query I get the following Exception:

> "Cannot find an entityType for resourceName: 'Make:#Edmunds'. 
>   Consider adding an 'EntityQuery.toType' call to your query or calling
>   the MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName method to register an
>   entityType for this resourceName."

What is wrong or missing here? How could I make the local query run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeze is interpretting your query .from() parameter as a resource instead of as a type. (which you appear to be trying to set)

To let Breeze know which type of entity you are trying to query, simply do as it suggest - chain a toType call onto your query -

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery .from("Make:#Edmunds").where("niceName", "startsWith", "A").toType('Make')
return manager.executeQueryLocally(query).then(returnResults);
```

Comment: manager.executeQueryLocally(query) returns the results synchronously - not a promise.  It should read: var results = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);